# Meteor SEO for each route/page

Tags: meteor

Using spiderable which works great for getting pages indexed. Trying to make each route have their own meta tags with the MS-Seo package statically like this:

```js
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'home',
        route_name: 'pageone',
        route_name: 'pagetwo'
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'home',
            title: '',
            meta: {
                'description': ''
            },
            og: {
                'title': '',
                'description' : '',
                'image': '',
                'url': '',
                'type': ''
            },
            twitter: {
                'card': 'summary_large_image',
                'site': '',
                'title': '',
                'description':'',
                'image': ''
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'pageone',
            title: '',
            meta: {
                'description': ''
            },
            og: {
                'title': '',
                'description' : '',
                'image': '',
                'url': '',
                'type': ''
            },
            twitter: {
                'card': 'summary_large_image',
                'site': '',
                'title': '',
                'description':'',
                'image': ''
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'pagetwo',
            title: '',
            meta: {
                'description': ''
            },
            og: {
                'title': '',
                'description' : '',
                'image': '',
                'url': '',
                'type': ''
            },
            twitter: {
                'card': 'summary_large_image',
                'site': '',
                'title': '',
                'description':'',
                'image': ''
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);
```

I get this error: "Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a function"

I've placed this into my project root older in a file called seosettings.js

What am I doing wrong?

Solved: 
Solved.

```
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'home'
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'home',
            title: '',
            meta: {
                ''
            },
            og: {
                "title": "",
                "image": "",
                "description": "",
                "url": "",
                "type":"website"
            },
            twitter: {
                "card":"",
                "site":"",
                "creator": "",
                "title":"",
                "description":".",
                "url": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);
```

Have to do it like this for each URL and placing the seosettings.js in the server folder.

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo/issues/69 I'll paste answer there once resolved.

Comment: what is this update? Is `SeoCollection` a regular collection? If so, why do you give it five arguments, three of which being a `$set` operation? where is `SeoCollection` defined?

Comment: To my understanding it's defined by the SEO package: https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo

Just Tested this: 

    SeoCollection.insert({
    "route_name" : "home", // the name of the Iron-Router route
    "title" : "Title of your home site",
    "meta" : [
        {"description": "This is the description of the document"},
        // add more meta tags
    ],
    "og" : [
        { "image": "http://your-domain.com/images/image.jpg" },
        // add more open graph tags
    ]
    })

Only the title comes through.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but, I solved movin the SEO.js into /lib folder

[image: lib "folder"]

I used the code how you,

```
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'location',
        route_name: 'router2',
        route_name: 'router3',
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'location',
            title: '............',
            meta: {
                'description': '...........'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'router2',
             title: '.......',
            meta: {
                'description': '.......'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'router3',
            title: '.......',
            meta: {
                'description': '.......'
            }
        }
    },
```

and Doesn't work, you must to make any SeoCollection.update for each router

```
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'location',       

    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'location',
            title: '.........',
            meta: {
                'description': '............'
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        upsert: true
    },
);

SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'router2',       

    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'router2',
            title: '.........',
            meta: {
                'description': '............'
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        upsert: true
    },
);
```

is the Only way how Work it!